# Как сделать после вывода информации чтобы при следующем срабатывании добавлялось +1?

Tags: javascript

после каждого нажатия на кнопку generate генерируются 2 случайных числа. После чего у кого число больше, тому и зачисляется победа. Всё в принципе работает, только побед зачисляется почему-то максимум 1. Дальше счётчик не хочет увеличиваться. Мне нужно чтобы счётчик у одной из сторон дошёл до 3 и сбросилось всё. Надеюсь кто-то сможет помочь.

```js
    function addName() {
    var arrContainer = document.getElementById('array');
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i < 1; i++) {
        while(
          typeof (arr[i] = prompt('Введите любое имя №'+i)) != 'string' || arr[i].length == 0
        );
    }
    arrContainer.innerHTML = arr;
    console.log(arr);
}
function generate(){
    var i = 0
    var usertype = document.getElementById('usercount')
    var admintype = document.getElementById('admincount')
    var userwin = document.getElementById('userwin')
    var adminwin = document.getElementById('adminwin')
    var score = document.getElementById('btnclick');
    const uniqueRandom = (...compareNumbers) => {
        let uniqueNumber;
        do {
            uniqueNumber = Math.floor(Math.random(1) * 50);
        } while(compareNumbers.includes(uniqueNumber));
        return uniqueNumber;
    };
    const numberOne = uniqueRandom();
    const numberTwo = uniqueRandom(numberOne);
    usertype.innerHTML=('NumberUser: '+ numberOne)
    admintype.innerHTML = ('NumberAdmin: '+ numberTwo)
    if(numberOne > numberTwo)
    userwin.innerHTML=("UserWin:" + i++)
    else {
        adminwin.innerHTML=("AdminWin: " + i++)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <button class="btn" onclick="return addName()">Enter your nick</button>
    <div id="array"></div>
    <div id="userwin"></div>
    <div id="usercount"> </div>
    <button id="btnclick" onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
    <div id="adminnick">admin</div>
    <div id="adminwin"></div>
    <div id="admincount"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вынесите переменную со счетчиком вне функции, или записывайте её куда-то и оттуда берите, условно в скрытый input или local storage...

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game.css">
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn" onclick="return addName()">Enter your nick</button>
<div id="array"></div>
<div id ="user-num"></div>
<div id="userwin" class="hidden">Userwin: <span class="count">0</span></div>
<button id="btnclick" onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
<div id="adminnick">admin</div>
<div id ="admin-num"></div>
<div id="adminwin" class="hidden">Adminwin: <span class="count">0</span></div>
</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```

js

```
 function addName() {
      var arrContainer = document.getElementById('array');
      var arr = [];
      for(var i=0; i < 1; i++) {
        while(
          typeof (arr[i] = prompt('Введите любое имя №'+i)) != 'string' || arr[i].length == 0
          );
      }
      arrContainer.innerHTML = arr;
      console.log(arr);
    }
    
    
    var userNumber = document.getElementById('user-num');
    var adminNumber = document.getElementById('admin-num');
    var userwinBlock = document.getElementById('userwin');
    var adminwinBlock = document.getElementById('adminwin');
    var userwinCountBlock = document.querySelector('#userwin .count');
    var adminwinCountBlock = document.querySelector('#adminwin .count');
    var userWinScore = 0;
    var adminWinScore = 0;
    
    let state = 'waiting';
    
    function generate(){
      if (state === 'preparing') {
        return;
      }
    
      state = 'waiting';
      var score = document.getElementById('btnclick');
    
      const uniqueRandom = (...compareNumbers) => {
        let uniqueNumber;
        do {
          uniqueNumber = Math.floor(Math.random(1) * 50);
        } while(compareNumbers.includes(uniqueNumber));
        return uniqueNumber;
      };
    
      const numberOne = uniqueRandom();
      const numberTwo = uniqueRandom(numberOne);
      console.log(userNumber, adminNumber);
      userNumber.innerHTML=('NumberUser: '+ numberOne)
      adminNumber.innerHTML = ('NumberAdmin: '+ numberTwo)
    
      console.log(adminwinCountBlock, userwinCountBlock);
      if (numberOne > numberTwo) {
        userwinCountBlock.innerHTML = ++userWinScore;
      } else {
        adminwinCountBlock.innerHTML = ++adminWinScore;
      }
    
      if (userWinScore >= 3 || adminWinScore >= 3) {
        const winner = userWinScore > adminWinScore ? 'user' : 'admin';
        alert(`finish, ${winner} won, score is: ${userWinScore} : ${adminWinScore}`);
        state = 'preparing';
        setTimeout(reset, 1000);
      }
    
      userwinBlock.classList.remove('hidden');
      adminwinBlock.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
    
    function reset() {
      userWinScore = 0;
      adminWinScore = 0;
    
      userwinCountBlock.innerHTML = 0;
      adminwinCountBlock.innerHTML = 0;
    
      userwinBlock.classList.add('hidden');
      adminwinBlock.classList.add('hidden');
    
      userNumber.innerHTML = '';
      adminNumber.innerHTML = '';
    
      document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = '';
      state = 'ready to start';
    }
```

css

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```